# LP Simplex algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, linear-programming

I need the robust C++ source code of the simplex algorithm (is a popular algorithm for numerical solution of the linear programming problem).

Please, no links to wikipedia. I need good source code in C++, using templates, clear user-friendly names and work very well.

Preferably algorithm must check the unstable floating-point calculation.

Comment: Show us what you've done so far, and what you're having trouble with.

Comment: So, how much are you willing to pay for someone to write this for you?

Comment: I hope that there is exist some free code for such well-known algorithm.

Comment: What's the reason to close this question? There are a lot of questions where people search good implementation of some algorithms. Googling doesn't give any reasonable quality assessment for implementations on the Internet. Voted to reopen.

Comment: This question is **not** ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and **can** be reasonably answered in its current form. If you're going to vote to close a question, at least give a real reason.

Answer (score 8):

This one is a C++ library: http://soplex.zib.de. But the license has some restrictions regarding commercial use.

This one has a liberal license, but is in C: http://aldebaran.devinci.fr/~cagnol/promotion2007/cs302/gsl/multimin/simplex.c.html
Probably you can write a thin wrapper.

Comment: The latter is not the simplex algorithm to solve linear programming problems, but the algorithm for nonlinear optimization by [Nelder and Mead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm)

Answer (score 6):

The Computational Infrastucture for Operations Research ([COIN-OR](http://www.coin-or.org/index.html)) provides open-source software for the operations research community, especially around numerical optimization. The CLP project, managed by John Forrest from IBM, implements the simplex algorithm for linear programming in C++.

Comment: I know it is a little old but just wanted to say that link is dead.

Answer (score 4):

Consider using C library [lpsolve](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/). It is not in C++, but it is the most stable and famous free linear programming solver based on the simplex method.